# Jquery Hover Failing on Child Div Entry

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that when I hover it swaps an image, and makes a div visible.  Everything seems fine, but when you enter the child div the hover fails and swaps the image back.  I thought that hover should continue through children as you are still hovering over the parent element.  I am using mouseenter and mouseleave on the text portion, tried that on the image swap, and it still would fain on entering the workerData div.

Here is the Code.

HTML

```
        <div id="workersAre">
            <div class="workers" id="anita">
                <div class="workerImage">
                    <img src="http://s28.postimg.org/biajzhy1p/anita.jpg" data-alt-src="http://s14.postimg.org/3v8gu1e0h/anita_Over.jpg" class="workerCover">
                </div>
                <div class="workerData">
                    <h1>Anita Art Maker</h1>
                    <h2>Arty, Art, Art</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
        #workerAre{
            width:100%;
        }
        .viveWorkers{
            width:100%;
            float:left;
            position:relative;
        }
        .workerImage{
            position:relative;
        }
        .workerCover{
            width:100%;
        }
        .workerData{
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            width:100%;
            text-align: center;
            display:none;
        }
```

Jquery

```
        var sourceSwap = function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                var newSource = $this.data('alt-src');
                $this.data('alt-src', $this.attr('src'));
                $this.attr('src', newSource);
            }

            $(function() {
                $('img[data-alt-src]').each(function() { 
                    new Image().src = $(this).data('alt-src'); 
                }).hover(sourceSwap, sourceSwap); 
            });
            $('.workers').mouseenter(function(){
                $(this).find('.workerData').show();
            });
            $('.workers').mouseleave(function(){
                $(this).find('.workerData').hide();
            });
```

Here is a link to a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fqn55yfs/).  Any input or a push in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image and the text are siblings. So when you hover over the text, the hover of the image ends.

Use the `.workers` element for hovering (as you did for showing and hiding the text) like so:

```
var sourceSwap = function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var newSource = $this.data('alt-src');
    $this.data('alt-src', $this.attr('src'));
    $this.attr('src', newSource);
}

$(function() {
    $('img[data-alt-src]').each(function() { 
        new Image().src = $(this).data('alt-src'); 
    });
});

$('.workers')
    .mouseenter(function(){
        sourceSwap.call($(this).find('img'));
        $(this).find('.workerData').show();
    })
    .mouseleave(function(){
        sourceSwap.call($(this).find('img'));
        $(this).find('.workerData').hide();
    });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fqn55yfs/1/)**

Or replace the last part with this:

```
$('.workers')
    .hover(function(){
        sourceSwap.call($(this).find('img'));
        $(this).find('.workerData').toggle();
    });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fqn55yfs/3/)**

Comment: That's it!  I should have realized the selector wasn't the div, it was the image!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to add `pointer-events:none;` to the text class. This makes the text div ignored by the hover listener and the event goes through it.

http://jsfiddle.net/fqn55yfs/4/

This means you can't select the text though. If you need user-interaction with the text, then use friedi's answer.